# In what basis does the Compton scattering measure a photon?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics

For example, the state of a right-handed polarized photon is:

\begin{equation}
|R\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|x\rangle + i|y\rangle)
\end{equation}

So theoretically, if we measure the photon in $\langle x|$ or $\langle y|$ basis, it has half the probability of giving x or y polarization. But the x and y directions are user-defined and the polarization takes a definite objective direction after measurement, how do we know which basis a photon is measured when it be Compton scattered? (since the differential cross-section is relevant to the polarization direction)